# PyQt - Capture Windows Key

Tags: python, windows, pyqt

I'm trying to catch the windows key because it keeps exiting out of my pyqt application because on windows 8 it takes you back to start screen i want to disable that i have:

```
def keyPressEvent(self, e):
    if e.key() == QtCore.Qt.Key_'need windows key name here':
        pass
```

but i dont know what the windows key name is ive tried just key_windows but that didnt work can someone point me to a list of all the keys? or tell me what the key is? thanks

Comment: Don't do that. If you disable the Windows key, what is the user supposed to do when he wants to do something that requires pressing the Windows key? Any program that took it on itself to disable keys on my keyboard would be kicked off my computer *immediately.*

Comment: its just from within this password appliation but when your done with that. it will be reenabled

Answer (score 1):

[Here](http://harmattan-dev.nokia.com/docs/library/html/qt4/qt.html#Key-enum) is a link to the different keys, and according to that page,

> On Windows Keyboards, Qt::MetaModifier and Qt::Key_Meta are mapped to
>   the Windows key.

Comment: My guess then is that the OS is catching it before it ever reaches your program. You can add a print statement to your keyPressEvent to see if it receives the Windows Key event when you press it, then debug from there.

Comment: its cactching the event it just not passing

Comment: If you print e.key() at that point it may give you an idea of what key it is seeing, if there's a possibility of you handling it.

Comment: it prints <built-in method key of QKeyEvent object at 0x0000000002B00B70>

Comment: print hex(e.key()) will show a value you can look up in the table on that page.

Comment: sorry to be a pain in the butt but i get an error print hex(e.key())
TypeError: hex(QTextStream): argument 1 has unexpected type 'int'

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/35633/discussion-between-raspberry-pi-and-radio)

Answer (score 0):

`Key_Super_L` and `Key_Super_R`

```
def keyPressEvent(self, e):
    if e.key() in (QtCore.Qt.Key_Super_L, QtCore.Qt.Key_Super_R):
        pass
```